# Is it possible to have a file ignore an htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using the folling line of code in my .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

The reason for this line is that the need for PHP is new. Adding this line to .htaccess is quicker and has less impact than changing every file extension to PHP.

However, there is a slight issue. One of our samples we want to demonstrate on the site does not render properly. It does when the line of code above is removed.

So is it possible to get that one sample folder to ignore the htaccess file in the site root?

Thanks

Comment: You can try removing the `.htaccess` in the root and place the `.htaccess` in the folder itself. You can also use a specific filename to be treated as PHP, instead of a global `.htm` if needed.

Comment: 99% of the site I want .htm to be read as PHP and only the one folder I don't. Was hoping that I wouldn't have to add manually add every page to htaccess file! Any thoughts?

Comment: If it's just the "one sample", why not just make up a `.php` file for it? I'll see what I can find in the meantime, but for now, that would seem to be the simpler solution.

Comment: The one sample is the only part of the site we don't want read as php, it is also made up of about 200files (JS, htm, css, images ect)

Comment: How do you make specific filenames treated as php?

Comment: `<Files index.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
</Files>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches I'd consider for this. The first is to add a second `.htaccess` file in the directory containing HTML only—this could use the `SetHandler` directive to override the php handler set in the root of the application.

EG (.htaccess in the HTML-only directory):

```
SetHandler default-handler
```

The second approach would be to use the `<Directory>` in the root `.htaccess` directive to set the handler.

EG (.htaccess in the document root):

```
<Directory /var/www/HTMLonly>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that is exactly what I was looking for (the top one).